# Early Christians understood "Scripture" to be the Old Testament alone?

Tags: reference-request, canon, scriptures

[Trent Horn's](https://www.catholic.com/audio/cot/a-neglected-argument-against-sola-scriptura) quote

> Modern scholars even doubt that they consider the New Testament a divinely inspired authority at all, much less a part of the only infallible rule of faith. Here’s some of those quotes, you might recognize them, I’ll share them in the debate. Michael Krueger, who shares a lot of views with Gavin, he tries to defend a model of the canon that will affirm sola scriptura. But he admits, for many modern scholars the key time is the end of the second century. Only then, largely due to the influence of Irenaeus, were these books first regarded as scripture. **The New Testament scholar, Gordon Fee, says the term scripture meant only the Old Testament for Christians until the end of the second century.**

Can you find the reference of Fee's book and some similar quotes about early Christians reference of "scripture" basically to mean the OT?

Comment: Notice. Focus on the question only. It's asking for source reference. This is not a debate topic for disagreement  I'm not questioning the quote exists but need the reference to read and cite it. You can't cite something to such website or youtube video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While commentating on 1st Timothy 5:17-18, Fee's book [*1st and 2nd Timothy, Titus*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/1_and_2_Timothy_Titus/PT4UAQAAMAAJ?hl=en) says:

> The formula the Scripture says technically introduces only the citation of Deut. 25:4. If Paul wrote (or dictated) these words, then Luke's Gospel had almost certainly not yet assumed written form. Many would argue that by using the formula Scripture for a saying in the Gospels, a later pseudepigrapher thereby betrayed himself. But in this case that will hardly work, since the term Scripture meant only the OT for Christians until the end of the second century. Even a writer at the end of the first century is not likely to have referred to a word of Jesus as "Scripture;' even though, of course, his words were fully authoritative for them (see graphe in Lampe's Patristic Lexicon for the evidence; d. 1 Clement, Ignatius, Polycarp, Justin, etc.). Very much as Mark says, "it is written in the prophet Isaiah" (1:2), and then cites Malachi and Isaiah, Paul writes, the Scripture says and cites "Scripture" itself, but then adds another authoritative word without necessarily meaning the term Scripture to apply to it. lt is altogether possible, as A. E. Harvey has argued, that the second citation was something of a proverb. However, Paul almost certainly intends to be citing what for him was already known to be a saying of Jesus.

For reference, 1st Timothy 5:17-18 says:

> 17 The elders who direct the affairs of the church well are worthy of double honor, especially those whose work is preaching and teaching. 18 For Scripture says, “Do not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain,” and “The worker deserves his wages.” (NIV)

I'm unsure why you are asking for further references from scholars saying the same thing, as Horn includes them [in the video you're referencing](https://www.catholic.com/audio/cot/a-neglected-argument-against-sola-scriptura).

But for those curious, Horn also cites Dr. Michael Kruger, John Allen Dearing (though I believe he gets the title of the book wrong), and Lee Martin McDonald as affirming that the New Testament only really gained prominence as scripture in the late second century.

Comment: Focus on the question only. We need the proper reference of the quote with context. He doesn't seem to care about referencing his claims. I'm not questioning it but if I wanna write or cite the same I will need reference with context.

Comment: If u can give all those references it will be great. Not just names. If quotes with proper references then even better.

Comment: @Michael16 I gave you the proper reference in the first paragraph of my answer - I’m confused what else you want? The very first quote is from Gordon Fee. Horn’s video also includes the book names he draws from in the video you referenced….

Comment: oh sorry, I didnt read your post and assumed it's some irrelevant early christian writings like others posted. I will accept your ans thanks. I think these scholars would agree that "scripture" refers to something of a relic or ancient authority; what things the NT writers left were later after some centuries became scripture to others. Some typo in your quote " meant anly the or for Christians"

Comment: and mention the book reference. 1 & 2 Timothy, Titus (Understanding the Bible Commentary Series) Gordon D. Fee · 2011

Comment: "the term Scripture meant anly the" is that supposed to be "only"?

Comment: @eques I copied from a PDF of the book and it must’ve copied over incorrectly. I think I fixed it but I’d have to go back and check

Comment: @Michael16 book reference is just above the first quote, cheers!

Comment: @LukeHill OCR can easily mistake an o for an a.

Comment: if you post from google books, do include the google books search results link, that is even better, not the actual book page link otherwise that link won't work if others use it directly.

Answer (score -2):

Polycarp who wrote circa CE 150 informs that the New Testament is Scripture.  He quotes Psalm 4:5 (note 405) and Ephesians 4:26 (note 406), calling both Scripture.

> For I trust that ye are well versed in the Sacred Scriptures, and that nothing is hid from you; but to me this privilege is not yet granted.404 It is declared then in these Scriptures, “Be ye angry, and sin not,”405 and, “Let not the sun go down upon your wrath.”406 [Polycarp, Epistle to the Philipians, Chapter XII](https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01/anf01.iv.ii.xii.html)

As well, the New Testament itself asserts it is Scripture.

> For the scripture saith, Thou shalt not muzzle the ox that treadeth out the corn. And, The labourer is worthy of his reward. 1 Timothy 5:18

The ox is a reference to Deuteronomy 25:4.  The laborer and reward refers to Luke 10:7.

EDITED TO ADD:

From Irenaeus in Against Heresies, he terms the New Testament quotes as Scripture.  First is an example of quotes and then his conclusion.

> They then represent the Saviour as having indicated this twofold faculty: first, the sustaining power, when He said, “Whosoever doth not bear his cross (Stauros), and follow after me, cannot be my disciple;”2702 and again, “Taking up the cross, follow me;”2703 but the separating power when He said, “I came not to send peace, but a sword.”2704 They also maintain that John indicated the same thing when he said, “The fan is in His hand, and He will thoroughly purge the floor, and will gather the wheat into His garner; but the chaff He will burn with fire unquenchable.”
> [Against Heresies, Book I, Chapter 3, Verses 1-6](https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01/anf01.ix.ii.iv.html)

> And others2710 of them, with great craftiness, adapted such parts of Scripture to their own figments,
> Ibid

And he says this about the New Testament as Scripture.

> Wherefore also Marcion and his followers have betaken themselves to mutilating the Scriptures, not acknowledging some books at all; and, curtailing the Gospel according to Luke and the Epistles of Paul, they assert that these are alone authentic, which they have themselves thus shortened.  AH, Book III, Chapter XII, Verse 12

So, to answer the OP, Mr. Fee's idea appears incorrect.

Comment: This is imprecise at best. One Christian writer using "Scripture" to include the New Testament doesn't mean that it was a widely-held opinion yet. And the idea that the New Testament asserts it is Scripture is not what the quote means. At best it means that the Gospel of Luke is Scripture, not the entire canon (which may not have even all been written at the point Paul wrote to Timothy)

Comment: Irenaeus who wrote circa CE 175 terms the NT as Scripture, but this was pointed out in the OP.  My two references are earlier.

Comment: But what is the quote from Irenaeus? Either way, the points I raise are not addressed.

Comment: see edited to add.  "Widely held" by whom?  The apostles, disciples, across the known world believed it.  Did certain other groups?  Of course not.  Irenaeus will affirm there are only 4 gospel (Mt, Mk, Lk, Jn).  Scripture.

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question being asked. The question wasn't "Is Fee correct in his claim that the New Testament wasn't held as scripture prior to the late second century", the question was for the quotes source and similar claims.

Comment: The quote in the question says "until the end of the second century" it seems reasonable that 175 is considered "end of the 2nd century" so what does that actually prove? plus @LukeHill's point about finding the source.

Comment: Further, no where in your quote uses the term "New Testament" nor do we find a complete list. He does use the term Scripture with reference to some NT texts, but there is a large difference between "Christians refer to the New Testament as Scripture" and "One theologian uses the term Scripture for some parts of the New Testament".

Comment: Focus on the question only. It's asking for source reference. This is not a debate topic for disagreement

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: @SLM how is the answer “no” on a question asking for a source?

Comment: Q: Can you find the reference of Fee's book and some similar quotes about early Christians reference of "scripture" basically to mean the OT? A: No.